# How can I mount davfs from within application?

Tags: c, linux, webdav

I have a remote filesystem I can mount through webdav via

```
sudo mount -t davfs https://myserver.com /tmp/dav
```

It prompts me for a username and password at this point.

I then added an entry to fstab and created a `~/.davfs2/secrets file`.
If I now run

```
mount /tmp/dav
```

It works.

Now I need this to be mounted from within my app automatically from C code.

If I call:

```
int result = mount("https://myserver.com", "/tmp/dav", "davfs", 0, "user,noauto,file_mode=600,dir_mode=700");
```

Mount returns result -1 and and errno is set to 19: strerror prints  "no such device".

The mount man page shows:

```
ENODEV filesystemtype not configured in the kernel.
```

How can I get this to work?  Is it because davfs is fuse based?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer turned out to be simpler than I thought.  I should point out I wanted to also remove the prompt for password.  This is how I solved it.

It turned out mount.davfs is a server that gets executed by the mount command.  But it's not a registered filesystem so you can't use the system mount(2) call.  Instead we must exec the mount command directly.

To provide my own secrets file I did this.

1. Mount tmpfs at /etc/davfs2 (hides real davfs2.conf etc)

   `mount("none", "/etc/davfs2/secrets", "tmpfs", 0, NULL);`
2. Create /etc/davfs2/secrets mode 0600 containing our secret
3. Run mount -t davfs url /yourpath (i.e. fork+exec the mount command)
4. Use webdav by reading and writing files in /yourpath
5. unmount /yourpath
6. unmount /etc/davfs2
7. exit program when done.

In addition I used unshare to hide the mount from outside the process.